# Cache file in memory and read in parallel

Tags: java, performance, file-io, randomaccessfile

I've a program (simple log parser) that's so slow couse in some cases it had to full scan input file. So I think to pre-cache the entire file (~100MB) in and read it with multiple thread.

With actual configuration I use the BufferedReader to do the "main read" and RandomAccessFile to goto onto specific offset and read what I need.

I've tried this way:

```
..
Reader reader = null;
if (cache) {
    // caching file in memory
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    buffer = new StringBuilder();
    for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
        buffer.append(line).append(CR);
    }
    br.close();
    reader = new StringReader(buffer.toString());
} else {
    reader = new FileReader(file);
}
br = new BufferedReader(reader);
for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
    offset += line.length() + 1; // Il +1 è per il line.separator
    matcher = Constants.PT_BEGIN_COMPOSITION.matcher(line);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        linecount++;
        record = new Record();
        record.setCompositionCode(matcher.group(1));
        matcher = Constants.PT_PREFIX.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            record.setBeginComposition(Constants.SDF_DATE.parse(matcher.group(1)));
            record.setProcessId(matcher.group(2));
            if (cache) {
                executor.submit(new PubblicationParser(buffer, offset, record));
            } else {
                executor.submit(new PubblicationParser(file, offset, record));
            }
            records.add(record);
        } else {
            br.close();
            throw new ParseException(line, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

In the `PubblicationParser` there is a `init()` method that choose what custom reader to use. A RandomAccessFileReader:

```
if (file != null) {
    this.logReader = new RandomAccessFileReader(file, offset);
} else if (sb != null) {
    this.logReader = new StringBuilderReader(sb, (int) offset);
}
```

And this is my 2 custom reader:

```
//
public class StringBuilderReader implements LogReader {
    public static final String CR = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    private final StringBuilder sb;
    private int offset;

    public StringBuilderReader(StringBuilder sb, int offset) {
        super();
        this.sb = sb;
        this.offset = offset;
    }

    @Override
    public String readLine() throws IOException {
        if (offset >= sb.length()) {
            return null;
        }
        int indexOf = sb.indexOf(CR, offset);
        if (indexOf < 0) {
            indexOf = sb.length();
        }
        String substring = sb.substring(offset, indexOf);
        offset = indexOf + CR.length();
        return substring;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
//
public class RandomAccessFileReader implements LogReader {
    private static final String FILEMODE_R = "r";
    private final RandomAccessFile raf;

    public RandomAccessFileReader(File file, long offset) throws IOException {
        this.raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, FILEMODE_R);
        this.raf.seek(offset);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        raf.close();
    }

    @Override
    public String readLine() throws IOException {
        return raf.readLine();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the "cache way" is so slow and I understand why!

Comment: ideas about what? whats your question?

Comment: You need: (0) A clear statement of a specific question.  (1) The code you are trying.  (2) What you expect it to do.  (3) What it *is* doing.

Comment: "Any ideas" is not a suitable question for this site. This is not a discussion forum.

Comment: sorry guyz, my bad ! i've posted what i've tried do to do without success

Answer (score 1):

You should be making sure that it is indeed the I/O making your application slow, not something else (e.g inefficient logic in your parser). For that, you could use a Java profiler (JProfiler, for example).

If it is indeed I/O, then it might be better to use some ready-made solution to load the file into memory - essentially that's what you are trying to implement yourself.

Have a look at [MappedByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) and [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

Comment: I'm sure that there's no unecessary I/O, couse in some situation (no exception or a few) the logic block that the 'PubblicationParser' has to read is small ( 30/50 rows ), so RAF is the best solution ( 12k block in 30'' ).If I try to read the same block with BufferedReader the elapsed time grow as far as I procede, couse ( I think ) it take an unnecessary cache. The problem is when I have a file with a lot of exception ( and stack traces too ), a logic block could be 2500 rows or more, and in this case it take a lot of time. Try to read what you link, thank you !